# AWS Cloudwatch Logs in WebApi .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, log4net, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm working on a C# WebAPI (.Net Framework 4.8) project that uses Log4Net. Currently this has a rolling file and LogEntries appender (both working). My client wishes to include an integration to AWS Cloudwatch in order to phase out LogEntries and bring logging into his AWS ecosystem.

I've added the following NuGet packages `AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs` and `AWS.Logger.Log4net` among other dependencies. I've also placed the following in my `App.config`:

```xml
<appender name="AWS" type="AWS.Logger.Log4net.AWSAppender,AWS.Logger.Log4net">
  <LogGroup>my_app</LogGroup>
  <Region>eu-west-1</Region>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <LibraryLogFileName>c:\logs\my_app_awslog.txt</LibraryLogFileName>
</appender>
```

I do not have access to the server from where this application is hosted, but have it under good authority that a credentials file has been placed in the default location using this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) as a guide. Also, it is to my knowledge that if the credentials file is incorrect, the NuGet library would log an error to `c:\logs\my_app_awslog.txt` as stipulated above.

Here's my problem:

1. No logs are arriving in AWS Cloudwatch.
2. No error logs from Cloudwatch NuGet library to the `c:\logs\my_app_awslog.txt` location.
3. Logs are still working to LogEntries as per normal so the Log4Net integration is still fine.

I'm unaware of any changes/setup that need to be made in AWS. Am I missing something?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the application is hosted on AWS EC2 instance, then the role associated with the instance should have permission to write to cloudwatch logs. If it is not EC2 server, the credentials used should have permission to write to cloudwatch logs. I suggest to confirm if the necessary permissions are in place.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm told the associated role with the EC2 instance has permission to write to cloudwatch logs.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in a small POC project with a similar set-up and configuration. However, the same thing worked fine in a Web Application project where there are a lot of log messages.

So I added a log message in a for loop and added debuggers at the beginning and ending lines to slow down the application. It worked sometimes but failed in some other cases.

Finally putting thread to sleep after a log message made it work consistently, but had to increase sleep time in some cases.

This is not suitable for a production application, but it might help to understand whether the configuration and set-up are correct or not.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("log4net.config"));
    AwsLogger.Info("Test log");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation has shown that the issue was that the `appender` was being ignored.
Within the `<log4net>` section, there is a `<root>` element that holds `appender-ref` keys. My appender was missing from this section.

E.g.

```
  <root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="AWS" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

By adding this, I now get logs to CloudWatch and any library specific errors are placed in `<LibraryLogFileName>c:\logs\my_app_awslog.txt</LibraryLogFileName>`.